# Unable to upload images to subfolders

Tags: php, image-uploading

I am trying to upload images into its respective folders using PHP. . There are totally 6 folders and 2 folders have subfolders. I have created a dropdown containing a list of folders and subfolders in a form and upon selecting a particular folder, an image can be uploaded into the selected folder. But when I select a subfolder, image is not getting uploaded.

Below is the following code for upload. And [here is the link](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/BLwXPv) for dropdowns (folders and subfolders using html).

```
if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {

$target_dir = "images/website/". $_POST["path"]."/";
}
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
$uploadOk = 1;
$imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
// Check if image file is a actual image or fake image
if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
$check = @getimagesize($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]);
if($check !== false) {
    echo '<script language="javascript">';
    echo 'alert("File is an image - " . $check["mime"] . ".")';
    echo '</script>';
    $uploadOk = 1;
} else {
    echo "File is not an image.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
}
// Check if file already exists
if (file_exists($target_file)) {
echo ("<SCRIPT LANGUAGE='JavaScript'>
window.alert('Sorry ! Image already exists!')
window.location.href='upload.php';
</SCRIPT>");
$uploadOk = 0;
}
// Check file size
if ($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["size"] > 5000000) {
echo ("<SCRIPT LANGUAGE='JavaScript'>
window.alert('Sorry ! Image file size is too large.')
window.location.href='upload.php';
</SCRIPT>");
$uploadOk = 0;
}
// Allow certain file formats
if($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType !=  "jpeg"
&& $imageFileType != "gif" && $imageFileType != "JPG" && $imageFileType !=    "PNG" && $imageFileType != "JPEG" && $imageFileType != "GIF") {
echo ("<SCRIPT LANGUAGE='JavaScript'>
window.alert('Sorry ! only JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF files are allowed')
window.location.href='upload.php';
</SCRIPT>");
echo ".";
$uploadOk = 0;
}
// Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
if ($uploadOk == 0) {
echo ("<SCRIPT LANGUAGE='JavaScript'>
window.alert('Sorry ! Image was not uploaded')
window.location.href='upload.php';
</SCRIPT>");
// if everything is ok, try to upload file
} else {
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
    // echo '<script language="javascript">';
    // echo 'alert("Image has been uploaded successfully!")';
    // echo '</script>';
 echo ("<SCRIPT LANGUAGE='JavaScript'>
 window.alert('Congrats ! Image has been successfully uploaded.')
 window.location.href='upload.php';
 </SCRIPT>");

    //header("Location:upload.php") ;
  //  echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]). " has    been uploaded.";
   } else {
    echo ("<SCRIPT LANGUAGE='JavaScript'>
  window.alert('Oops Sorry ! There was some error.')
  window.location.href='upload.php';
  </SCRIPT>");

   // echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
  }
  }
  ?>
```

Comment: try with `$target_dir = "/images/website/". $_POST["path"]."/";`

Comment: I have used this code already

Comment: @devpro I am not sure if I have to use a condition to use 2 different paths, one for folder and other for subfolder.

Comment: Share your  dropdown containing a list of folders and subfolder.

Comment: @Hakan Sonmez  Here is the codepen for dropwodn http://codepen.io/anon/pen/BLwXPv

Comment: Which one is the subfolder and does not work It is not clear. You should check $_POST['pah'] value for every option. And you must compare your real folders name. So create a file and write in it
option value | $_POST['path'] value | folder name and permissions

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your directory and subdirectories have proper file permissions to perform file upload on that path

Make sure there are no restricting options set in .htaccess file which will restrict file upload in subdirectory.

Comment: Please read the code and suggest a suitable answer. All i need is a condition to select different paths for different selections.